# Microsoft Teams Bot - Build tabs with Adaptive Cards does not allow me to specify a `contentBotId` in the UI

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards, teams-toolkit

I am developing a Microsoft Teams bot app and currently i'm adding a new Static Tab developed with AdaptiveCards [as documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/build-adaptive-card-tabs).

I've followed the documentation and at some point it says that **"Provide the `contentBotId` property with the botId that the Adaptive Card tab must communicate with."**, which is what i've done to develop the feature in my "test" environment by manually modifying the `manifest` file and adding the values that expects.

Now, in my production bot via the [teams portal](https://dev.teams.microsoft.com/apps/) i expect to find a choice for adding this feature into the bot, but it's not.
The only thing that i can add is this:

[image: Non static tab allowed?]

which, as shown, it requires a `contentUrl` but it shouldn't based on the MS documentation:
**"Static tab definitions must contain either a contentBotId, specifying an Adaptive Card tab ***OR*** a contentUrl, specifying a typical hosted web content tab experience."**

---

### Question:

How i am supposed to add this feature into my production bot without having the ability from the teams portal? Mind that portal also doesn't allow you to modify the manifest file, and if i do manually i have to re-import the bot into the portal which means new id's, new submission?.

Comment: We are checking this with engineering team. We will update you soon.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I'm waiting for your feedback.

Comment: We are still checking this with engineering team. We will let you know once we have any updates on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We got a confirmation from engineering team that currently creation of adaptive card tab via developer portal is not supported.

If you wish, you may vote for this feature on [Microsoft Teams · Community](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472)

Comment: Thank's for your answer.
Any idea how can i deal with this so we can push this to our production instances? I mean a submission of the bot manifest modified with the required properties would do the trick? (And if so, would the developer portal get updated somehow?)

Comment: Already there is feature request raised for this. You can manually add the contentBotId in manifest and upload it in Teams.